# How to handle ListView sorting performance?

Tags: react-native, react-native-listview

I have a `ListView` that displays a list of chat sessions (similar to Whatsapp/Facebook Messenger), with the following `rowHasChanged`:

```
rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1.id !== r2.id
```

I noticed that items that are not being updated are getting re-rendered, even if I use `shouldComponentUpdate`.

After some traces I found out that because I sort the items differently before cloning the dataSource (new message makes items jump to the top of the list), `rowHasChanged` is comparing different rows. It makes sense for it to do that.

But isn't there a solution for it to support sorting in a performant manner? In WPF we had a `CollectionViewSource` that received [something to sort by](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.sortdescriptions(v=vs.110).aspx) in addition to it's data because of the same issue (also supported filtering and others).

Does anyone know a way to get rid of these redundant renders?

Comment: `ListViewDataSource` uses immutable data so I don't think it'll be possible using a `ListView`.  However, if you have the `removeClippedSubviews` enabled, it doesn't seem like it should be rendering very many rows.  Have you tried that?

Comment: @GarrettMcCullough The problem isn't about immutable data or rendering too many rows. It's that when one row changes it's position it causes all the other rows to change their position in my data, which causes the ListView to deem ALL the rows as changed rows because it's comparing different rows to each other.

Comment: Moti, my comment was meant to say that because you're using an immutable data object, pushing a new record to the front of the queue *is* changing the data structure and will therefore require every row to be re-rendered because the data structure is now different.  However, if you have `removeClippedSubviews` turned on, it won't really matter that you're re-rendering all of the rows because you'll only be re-rendering the visible rows (plus a few extra on either side) so it shouldn't cause a performance issue.  You might also look at some of the ListView alternatives

Comment: @GarrettMcCullough Immutable array won't be a problem here. This is the reason we have `rowHasChanged`, to know which rows should re-render. You are correct in saying that I should be taking the price of re rendering only for my visible rows, but still if I have 2 visible rows, that reverse their positions in my data (from index 0 to 1 or something) they will both be re-rendered, although never changed. Just switched position.

Answer (score 0):

Are u using dataSource like this?

```js
this.setState({
    dataSource: this.ds.cloneWithRows(rowData)
});
```

Try to use like this:

```js
this.setState(state => ({
    dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(rowData)
}))
```

In the first sutiation, you're set a new value to dataSource ,so it won't use rowHasChanged,and takes it like a new dataSource.

Comment: No, I was using my data source from the state consistently. The issue isn't about rowHasChanged, it's about the fact you can't sort the ListView without causing probably unnecessary re-renders because the row comparison is solely index based.